# JSON cross site without JSONP

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I have a local piece of hardware that I access via it's IP address to retrieve json data.

I am creating a web based app but it can not access the local json data when the app is running on the web due to cross domain issues.

Is there a suitable solution to make the JSON data available to the web app?

I'm using jQuery to read the JSON file locally.

The hardware currently doesn't provide JSONP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can proxy it with a PHP/ASP/etc. page on your local site that (in the back-end) will query the remote information. This will allow you to call somesite.com/getForeignData (which actually calls othersite.com/foreignData) and return it within the same domain.

Other than that, you're going to need to use JSONP (this is a boundary purposely set). The "last" option is to enable cross-boundary calls on **your** browser, but if you want others to have the same ability, this is only a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add header to the HTTP Response? If yes, add the following

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the value `*`

then your browser will allow the request for that resource

Comment: For those curious about this method, it is otherwise known as [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local proxy.

For example, if your web app is running at www.example.com, make a small server-side component that responds at www.example.com/hardware.

Then, upon calling this URL the server-side component performs a direct query to the hardware and returns it to the calling webapp.

Things to note:

- If the response is large or the hardware is slow, your proxy may have to buffer a lot.  If you want to make a solution that scales, you'll have to be careful.
- You can do caching of the data at your proxy to reduce the load on the hardware
- You can massage the data before sending it to the web app in your proxy. For example, change from JSON to XML or vice versa. Or even pre-format it to HTML...

Answer (score 0):

As Brad mentioned using a proxy is the way to go. Here's some more information on proxies:

http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

If you have access to a php server, I can recommend the proxy by http://www.troywolf.com/articles/. You'll need the following:

- http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_http/proxy.phps
- http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_http

Answer (score 0):

If your url looks something like this
http://<IPAddress>/RequestedJson
then you might use [flXHR](http://flxhr.flensed.com/) which is quite convenient.

1) Import the libraries of flXHR
2) Simply create an instance of flXHR
3) Then assign it to jQuery Ajax options

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   "xhr": myflXHRInstance
});
```

(more info in [ajaxOptions page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))
4)
Put crossdomain.xml in the root of your ip i.e.
http://<IPAddress>/crossdomain.xml [More info about crossdomain.xml](http://wiki.flash-ripper.com/?title=Crossdomain.xml)

5) Enjoy your crossdomain requests via jQuery ))

P.S. Requires the flash plugin to be installed. There are almost no browsers that do not have Flash player plugin installed. [Riastats](http://www.riastats.com/)

EDIT: Sorry for russian link for crossdomain.xml.
[Crossdomain.xml example](http://curtismorley.com/2007/09/01/flash-flex-tutorial-how-to-create-a-crossdomainxml-file/)

Comment: If you do this, do not be tempted to put allow-access-from domain="*", because that will leave your site open for any site to read your content. The problem is you would have to put the crossdomain.xml on your hardware device, which may not be possible.