# json cross origin not working with callback=?

Tags: jquery, json, callback, getjson

I have a issue on getting JSON data on mangaeden.com . Let me explain:

If I use this script

```
$.getJSON('http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/1/', function(data) {

            $.each(data.manga, function(key, val) {
                something();
            });
        });
```

I get the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error".
So I use a callback:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/1/?&callback=?', function(data) {

            $.each(data.manga, function(key, val) {
                something();
            });
        });
```

Now the server send me the json data but it is evalueted as script so I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error

How the freak can I do?

Comment: apparently the API is broken or just doesn't support jsonp

Comment: In your backend try adding prefix to the result with something like `m=` as if you are assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I think I don't undestrood this but I'm not the owner of mangaeden.com so I can't edit backend

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution with YQL

The YQL Query [click](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20json%20where%20url=%22http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/1/%22)

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/gJCk3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the '&' sign before 'callback'.

Comment: Are you sure they support json callbacks?

Comment: No I'm not sure. I just want to get the json data I don't care how. I'm freking out :(

The problem is that I don't know why the data is interpreted as a script if I put the callback parameter

Comment: Use could get in PHP, if you use that?

Answer (score 0):

you should be change this api http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/1/?callback=jsonpcb..
the result must be like this

```
jsonpcb({
  "manga": [
    {
      "i": "4e70ea93c092255ef70074f3",
      "a": "dragonball-af",
      "im": null,
      "t": "DragonBall AF"
    },
..
});
```

Comment: if I put something as a callback parameter (es. callback=jsonpcb) I get the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.
    
    $.getJSON('http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/1/?callback=jsonpcb', function(data) {

    something();
    });
   });
function jsonpcb(data){
   alert(data);
   }

Comment: you modify also your api, inserting the jsonpCallback

Comment: Ok, but I need to get that JSON data in any way. Maybe I can simply do an HTTP request?

Comment: you find the possible solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077781/json-cross-site-without-jsonp but you shoud implement a proxy service