# jQuery feed processing

Tags: jquery, jsonp, feed

we are trying to consume a feed from a web site. We have tried different approaches but none of them are working:

Approach 1: Trying to get the content and parse it manually

```
$.get("http://www.wwe.com/feeds/sapphire/news/all/all/0,1", {}, function(data){
  alert(data);
 });
```

we always get an empty response. If you paste the URL in the browser window you get a valid response (http://www.wwe.com/feeds/sapphire/news/all/all/0,1)

Approach 2: Using jsonP

We have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.wwe.com/feeds/sapphire/news/all/all/0,1",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {},
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {
        console.log("error");
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('success_function');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Server is responding with invalid label. It seems that in the response the callback function is missing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Let me guess, you get a Access-Control-Allow-Origin warning in your console?

Comment: No, we get SyntaxError: invalid label. Is there any way to get the unparsed string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the service you are attempting to load from doesn't support jsonp.  Without this you can't do a straight jquery ajax call to it across domains.

See: [JSON cross site without JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077781/json-cross-site-without-jsonp)

You can test this by keeping your code the same and testing a url that does support jsonp (e.g. https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=espn&count=1)

The only alternative appears to create a proxy on your sever to pass the data through to your javascript.